# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (AppComponent.html:34)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a post request to a `nestJS` server from an Angular app using HttpClient and [(ngModel)] directives in the form. When I submit the form I get the following error:

```
AppComponent.html:34 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at AppComponent.addBook (app.component.ts:21)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:34)
    at handleEvent (core.js:38098)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:39716)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:39352)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:25818)
    at core.js:37030
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:1789)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
```

Here is the `component.html` file which uses the 'id' property of the undefined variable, which should really be the books object:

```
//app.component.html

<form class="" action="addBook()" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">


    <label for="id">Book ID:</label>
    <input id="id" name="bookID" type="text" [(ngModel)]="id" class="form-control">

    <label for="title">Book Title:</label>
    <input id="title" name="bookTitle" type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" class="form-control">

    <label for="description">Book Description:</label>
    <input id="description" name="bookDescription" type="text" [(ngModel)]="description" class="form-control">

    <label for="author">Book Author:</label>
    <input id="author" name="bookAuthor" type="text" [(ngModel)]="author" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" name="button" (click)="addBook()">add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

All the properties used in [(ngModel)] directives belong to a books object, defined in the `app.component.ts` file :

```
//app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Book } from './book';
@Component({

  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  book: Book;
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService){}
    library = {};
ngOnInit(){
}
    getBooks() {
      this.apiService.getBooks().subscribe(data => this.library = data);
    };
    addBook(){
       let book = {
        id: this.book.id,
        title: this.book.title,
        description: this.book.description,
        author: this.book.author
      }
      this.apiService.addBook(book).subscribe(
        success => alert("Done"),
        error => alert(error)
      )
    }

    clearview() {
      this.library = {}
    };

}
```

This book object is of type Book which is a class that looks like this:

```
export class Book{
  id: Number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  author: string;
}
```

Sorry if I've made this longer than it needed to be, I wanted to give the full context since I've tried many different approaches to fixing this error.

Comment: Well book is never *initialized / set to a value* so how can you `id: this.book.id` if book is `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

Change app.component.html to this :

```
<form class="" action="addBook()" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">


    <label for="id">Book ID:</label>
    <input id="id" name="bookID" type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.id" class="form-control">

    <label for="title">Book Title:</label>
    <input id="title" name="bookTitle" type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.title" class="form-control">

    <label for="description">Book Description:</label>
    <input id="description" name="bookDescription" type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.description" class="form-control">

    <label for="author">Book Author:</label>
    <input id="author" name="bookAuthor" type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.author" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" name="button" (click)="addBook()">add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

read more at

> [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)